# Find $\vec u$ such that $D_\vec uf(x^2+y^2)$ is maximum, minimum, and zero at $(1,2)$

Tags: vector-spaces

I understand how to find the maximum and minimum, but I'm having trouble understanding how to find it when it's zero. My professor said that I need to set $\phi=\pi/2$ in $D_uf(x,y)=\|\nabla f\|\cos{\phi}$. But $\cos{\pi/2}=0$, so wouldn't it make the entire expression equal to $0$?

My calculations for finding maximum and minimum:

$\nabla f(x,y)=\langle 2x,2y\rangle$
$\nabla f(1,2)=\langle 2,4\rangle$
$\|\nabla f(1,2)\|=2\sqrt{5}$

To get maximum, let $\vec u=\frac{\nabla f(1,2)}{\|\nabla f(1,2)\|}$, which yields $\bigl\langle\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\bigr\rangle$. To get minimum, I just negate the vector, which yields $\bigl\langle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\bigr\rangle$.

How do I find $\vec u$ when it's equal to $0$?

Comment: You wrote at the end of the first parraph: "... so wouldn't it make the entire expression equal to 0?" Yes, of course: isn't that what you're asked to do?!

Comment: I was, but that doesn't make sense. It's going to be zero for every problem. Is there a different way to ask it? Instead of zero, say that it's leveled?

Comment: Do you think that **all** the vectors form the same angle with the given one?

Comment: No, that's exactly my question: how do I find it for this specific vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function is differentiable, I'd rather use the formula

$$D_uf(x,y)=\nabla f(x,y)\cdot u\;,\;\;u=\text{a unit vector in the wanted direction}\implies$$

$$\nabla f(1,2)\cdot (u_1,u_2)=(2,4)\cdot (u_1,u_2)=2u_1+4u_2=0\iff u_1=-2u_2$$

and we're done...!